# NSDate off while calculating last monday's date

Tags: objective-c, nsdate

I have a problem with my function that is supposed to retrieve this week's monday's date.

Sometimes it's a day off:

```
+(NSDate *) lastMondayBeforeDate:(NSDate*)timeStamp {
    NSCalendar *gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
    NSDateComponents *comps = 
    [gregorian components:NSWeekdayCalendarUnit fromDate:timeStamp];
    NSInteger weekday = [comps weekday];
    weekday = weekday==1 ? 6 : weekday-2; 
    NSTimeInterval secondsSinceMondayMidnight =  
    (NSUInteger) [timeStamp timeIntervalSince1970] % 60*60*24 + 
    weekday * 60*60*24;

    NSLog(@"MONDAY's DATE-----------%@", [timeStamp dateByAddingTimeInterval:-secondsSinceMondayMidnight]);
    return [timeStamp dateByAddingTimeInterval:-secondsSinceMondayMidnight];
}
```

Comment: Why `weekday==1`?  Sunday is 1 and monday is 2.

Comment: to start with 0 on monday rather than 1 on sunday

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apple has [code demonstrating how to do almost exactly this](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DatesAndTimes/Articles/dtCalendricalCalculations.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007836-SW12).  They are targeting the Sunday of the week instead of Monday, but you can just add 1 in the appropriate place to adjust.

You definitely don't want to be doing things like `60*60*24` and computing seconds to adjust by. For example, days can have more or less than 24 hours due to changes in Daylight Saving Time.